# Preview mails in staging server on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a staging server where I want the designers to be able to preview the email design.
I have used rails 4 feature and I am able to access the mailer preview in localhost on path

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers
```

Can I do the same on the staging server ?

Comment: where are you hosting?

Comment: I host on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

this is all about configuration

first thing that you should do is to environment for staging. 
by default rails give you development, production, and test

then I would set up something like [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) this way emails dont go out to real people that dont need to see them.

last step is to configure the server environment to be staging

> You can also edit config vars on your app’s settings tab on Dashboard
>   Heroku manifests config vars as environment variables to the
>   application. These environment variables are persistent – they will
>   remain in place across deploys and app restarts – so unless you need
>   to change values, you only need to set them once. Whenever you set or
>   remove a config var, your app will be restarted.

[image]

but here is were you need to change production to staging

I hope that this helps